# cytoscape.js and Angular6

Tags: angular6, cytoscape.js

I want to import [cytoscape.js](http://js.cytoscape.org/) library in my angular project, but I don't know how to do it. As far as I know, there is no official cytoscape module for angular, is there any way to import cytoscape manually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UPDATE: Please see the answer of D.C. Joo, this should be the accepted answer.

Actually, it's no problem to import JS libraries in Angular, thats how I do it using npm and Angular6:

1. Run `npm install cytoscape`
2. Download Cytoscape from `https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/master/dist/cytoscape.min.js`
3. Create a directory `scripts` in your Angular root directory and place the downloaded file there
4. Include your downloaded script in your `angular.json`:

   "projects": {
   "myproject": {
     ...
     "architect": {
       "build": {
         ...
           "scripts": [
               "src/scripts/cytoscape.min.js"
           ]
         ...
   (NOTE: Sorry about the formatting, I tried but it does not want to work)
5. In the Angular component where you want to use Cytoscape, add `declare var cytoscape: any;` to the imports

Now you can use Cytoscape like you would normally, have fun :)

Comment: thank you very much, I did exactly the same but guiding me from this example: https://github.com/asiftasleem/angular-2-cytoscape

Answer (score 25):

Philipp's answer actually works but it looks like an improper inclusion of a library using both `npm install` AND an actual JS file. You can skip the `npm install` step from the instruction and it will work the same.
To actually use npm installed package I advise the following:

1. Run `npm install cytoscape`
2. Run `npm install --save @types/cytoscape` for proper IDE tips.
3. In your component add `import * as cytoscape from 'cytoscape';`
4. Use it like expected e.g. `let cy = cytoscape({...})`

Comment: Sounds logical. I think we have very similar approach in our application. It deserves to be accepted answer, because of proper usage of both npm isntall workflow and tips for IDE...

Comment: Exactly, this should be the accepted answer. I didn't know much about the correct workflow when I wrote my answer but still wanted to provide my solution since it did work. However, it is reduntant and dirty. Do it this way!