# Cytoscape.js cannot access class variables and services when node is clicked

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cytoscape.js

I'm trying to combine Cytoscape.js and Angular7 referring below question.
[cytoscape.js and Angular6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51470913/cytoscape-js-and-angular6)

To handle node click event, I implemented cy.on().
This function works, but it cannot access class variables or services.

How can I access them in local function on cy.on()?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Someservice } from './some.service'
declare var cytoscape: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: '<div id="cy"></div>',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})

let foobar:string = 'bar'

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  cy: any;
  foo:string = 'bar';

  constructor(private someservice: Someservice){}

  ngOnInit() {
      this.InitGraph()
      this.addListner()
  }

  NodeClicked(nodeid) {
      console.log(nodeid) //doesn't work
  }

  addListner(){
    this.cy.on('tap', 'node', function(evt){
      var node = evt.target;
      console.log( 'tapped ' + node.id() ); //this works
      console.log(this.foo) //doesn't work and "undefined" is shown
      this.NodeClicked(node.id()) //doesn't work and "this.NodeClicked is not function" is shown
      this.someservice.somefunc(node.id()) // doesn't work and "somefunc" is not defined is shown.
      console.log(foobar) // this work
    });
  }

  InitGraph(){
    this.cy = cytoscape({
      container: document.getElementById('cy'),

      elements: [
        { data: { id: 'a' } },
        { data: { id: 'b' } },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'ab',
            source: 'a',
            target: 'b'
          }
        }]
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using the `function` keyword in your callback to the `this.cy.on` method, the `this` keyword will be set either to the global object (probably `window`) (if you are not in strict mode) or to `undefined` (if you are in strict mode). Alternatively it may be set to a different value by cytoscape itself. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context

The cytoscape source indicates that in this case `this` is being set to some other value. https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/2205c12fe4c6925a1727d7387c84e12b169c1a9e/src/emitter.js#L219

There's two ways you should be able to get the `this` value of your component:

### Option 1

Use an arrow function as the callback, as in arrow functions, `this` retains the value of the enclosing lexical context's `this`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Arrow_functions

```js
addListner(){
  this.cy.on('tap', 'node', e => {
    var node = e.target;
    console.log('tapped ' + node.id());
    console.log(this.foo);
  }
}
```

### Option 2

Call a new method on your component, as in this case `this` is set to the object the method is called on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method

```js
addListner(){
  this.cy.on('tap', 'node', e => this.onNodeClicked(e));
}

onNodeClicked(e) {
  var node = e.target;
  console.log('tapped ' + node.id());
  console.log(this.foo);
}
```